# Try catch block causing infinite loop?

Tags: java, try-catch, infinite-loop

I am writing a simple java console game. I use the scanner to read the input from the console. I am trying to verify that it I ask for an integer, I don't get an error if a letter is entered. I tried this:

```
boolean validResponce = false;
int choice = 0;
while (!validResponce)
{
    try
    {
        choice = stdin.nextInt();
        validResponce = true;
    }
    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("I did not understand what you said. Try again: ");
    }
}
```

but it seems to create an infinite loop, just printing out the catch block. What am I doing wrong.

And yes, I am new to Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nextInt()` won't discard the mismatched output; the program will try to read it over and over again, failing each time. Use the `hasNextInt()` method to determine whether there's an `int` available to be read before calling  `nextInt()`.

Make sure that when you find something in the `InputStream` other than an integer you clear it with `nextLine()` because `hasNextInt()` also doesn't discard input, it just tests the next token in the input stream.

Comment: Brilliant!!! So I could just get rid of the try-catch all together!

Comment: @Adam8797 Similarly, make sure that when you find something in the InputStream other than an integer you clear it with `nextLine()` because `hasNextInt()` also doesn't discard input, it just tests the next token in the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
boolean isInValidResponse = true;
//then
while(isInValidResponse){
//makes more sense and is less confusing
    try{
        //let user know you are now asking for a number, don't just leave empty console
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        String lineEntered = stdin.nextLine(); //as suggested in accepted answer, it will allow you to exit console waiting for more integers from user
        //test if user entered a number in that line
        int number=Integer.parseInt(lineEntered);
        System.out.println("You entered a number: "+number);
        isInValidResponse = false;
    }
//it tries to read integer from input, the exceptions should be either NumberFormatException, IOException or just Exception
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("I did not understand what you said. Try again: ");
    }
}
```

Because of common topic of `avoiding negative conditionals` https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/09/the-inspection-connection-issue-2/